# Bitbucket - How to get access token?

Tags: javascript, bitbucket

I am developing a javascript application ( electron , react ) in which i want to show a user his bitbucket repositories. I can show all public repositories simply using url "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{username}" . But I need private repositories too. How to get them ? I need to get access token for it. How to get tokens using user credentials ???

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: OAuth dude... oauth authentication

Answer (score 0):

I think this discussion would help you in determining what you might need (but not exact)

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/I-am-unable-to-find-HTTP-access-tokens-in-my-profile/qaq-p/2004278

Apparently, for personal bitbucket account, we only have the option to use api-tokens

Answer (score -2):

For obtaining Access token you can obtain from this links

```
https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize
https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token
```

Before this you need to login in you account.
For this you also need to access permissions uisng curl and terminal(not sure).In some cases token expire in an hour and you will get 401 response.Then you need to refresh tokens